# "Cross Origin Request Blocked" No solutions seem to work

Tags: node.js, express, cors, mern

**Background**

I'm building a MERN full stack application as a personal project. I am running the frontend client on localhost:3000 and the server on localhost:5000.

**Problem**

All of my API routes work as expected except for a GET request, `router.get('/get-friends', ...)` which queries the mongoDB to return a list of collection documents. Calling that get request on Postman returns the expected output. I decided to write a simple GET request that returns a method and it works just fine in my browser

When making the request the get-friends request in my browser, I get the following log:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/users/get-friends/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

**What I've Already Tried**

- Enabling cors in my Express server
- Enabling cors preflight
- Adding a proxy to the server from the client's package.json
- Switching from Axios to vanilla JS's fetch() method
- Turning off cors in my browser

I suspect the issue occurs when I make the request to the database from Express. I am really not sure how to solve this issue.

Here is the route in question:

```
router.get('/get-friends', (req, res) =>{
  var species_ = req.body.species;
  var gender_ = req.body.gender;
  var neutered_ = req.body.neutered;

  // query db
  Friend.find({species: species_},{gender:gender_},{neutered:neutered_}).then((friends_) =>{
    if(!friends_){
      return res.status(404).send('query error, nothing returned');
    }
    return res.send(friends_);
  }).catch((e) =>{
    res.status(400).send(4);
  })
});
```

[Here is the project repo](https://github.com/edgarvi/foster-friends) and the relevant files are:

```
https://github.com/edgarvi/foster-friends/server.js (Express server)
https://github.com/EdgarVi/foster-friends/blob/master/routes/api/users.js (Routes for the express server)
https://github.com/EdgarVi/foster-friends/blob/master/client/src/components/layout/SearchFriends.js (React component which calls the server)
```

I would gladly appreciate any help!

Comment: Is the client sending an OPTIONS request? Does the response headers contain a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: Yes, the client sends an OPTIONS request and the response header contains a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with it's value: *. I also tried enabling cors for all options routes with no luck.

Comment: It looks like the client is sending the request with an additional path at the end, is this intentional? Your route doesn't appear to be expecting a request in that format. `http://localhost:5000/api/users/get-friends/.` vs `http://localhost:5000/api/users/get-friends`

Comment: I have amended both URLs to be: `http://localhost:5000/api/users/get-friends` for now. I have tried to enable cors preflight by enabling cors for all options routes however that does not solve the issue either.

Comment: Have you tried being explicit with the allowed origin instead of using a wildcard? This shouldn't be necessary for a GET request, but that's where I would look next.

Comment: I have changed `app.use(cors())` to `app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))`. In the OPTIONS and GET request headers I find: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
http://localhost:3000` but I am still getting `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`.

Comment: Does this happen if you use a different browser?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this in Chrome and Firefox. On both browsers my OPTIONS route has status: 204 and the GET request does not get a response other than Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any more suggestions. I will say that it's extremely unlikely that it has anything to do with the database interaction, I suppose you could test that out by sending some hardcoded response.

Answer (score 0):

I have highlighted possible problems.

Reason: CORS request did not succeed

> The HTTP request which makes use of CORS failed because the HTTP
>   connection failed at either the network or protocol level. The error
>   is not directly related to CORS, but is a fundamental network error of
>   some kind.
>
> ***> In many cases, it is caused by a browser plugin (e.g. an ad blocker or
>   privacy protector) blocking the request.***
>
> Other possible causes include:
>
> Trying to access an https resource that has an invalid certificate
>   will cause this error.
>
> Trying to access an http resource from a page with an https origin
>   will also cause this error.
>
> As of Firefox 68, https pages are not permitted to access
>   http://localhost, although this may be changed by Bug 1488740.
>
> ***> The server did not respond to the actual request (even if it responded
>   to the Preflight request). One scenario might be an HTTP service being
>   developed that panicked without returning any data.***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help and the suggestions. After struggling through this for multiple days, I finally encountered a solution.

In my react client, I made the API call:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/get-friends',
            {
                params: {
                    species: this.state.species,
                    gender: this.state.gender,
                    neutured: neutered_
            }}
        );
```

and then I changed the Mongoose query to look like:

```
router.get('/get-friends', (req, res) =>{
  var species_ = req.query.species;
  var gender_ = req.query.gender;
  var neutered_ = req.query.neutered;

  // query db
  Friend.find({species: species_},{gender:gender_},{neutered:neutered_}).then((_friends) => {
    return res.send(_friends);
  })
});
```

I'm not exactly sure why these changes made my code finally work but once again, thank you all for the help and suggestions!